# C#: reason behind misleading message for InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, exception, .net

This particular question is more about trying to see the reason behind compiler message than solving a problem, but I hope it's okay.

Let's say we have:

```
class Foo {
    public static explicit operator Foo(Bar bar) {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

The implementation of `Bar` is not important. Now, when you try the following, the exception occurs:

```
object obj = new Bar();
Foo foo = (Foo)obj;
```

It gives the `InvalidCastException`, and rightly so, because we have no casting operator for `object` type. But the exception message is:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Bar' to type 'Foo'

Which is kind of misleading because I obviously **can** cast object of type `Bar` to type `Foo`. I would expect the compiler to tell me that I am basically trying to cast an object of type `System.Object`, not `Bar`. 
Is my understanding flawed and if so, what's the reason behind this behavior?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Just to be clear, I **know** how to handle the issue and that `Foo foo = (Foo)(Bar)bar` will do the trick. I am more curious about the error message itself.

Comment: I think it should be `Foo foo = (Foo)obj;` Have you tried `var obj = new Bar();` instead?

Comment: @Scoregraphic: you're right, it should be `Foo foo = (Foo)obj`, corrected the question now

Comment: Check out obj.GetType().Name it would be showing **Bar**

Comment: @V4Vendetta: yes, I know that, I just don't see how this information is helpful in this particular message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what else can the message say?

If it said "*Unable to cast object of type 'object' to type 'Foo'*", that would be misleading and less useful because `obj` isn't an instance of `object`, and you wouldn't have any way of knowing what `obj` *is* an instance of.

The other alternative would be something along the lines of "*Unable to cast object of type 'Bar' (Referenced as 'object') to type 'Foo'*", but that's verbose and kind of confusing. Maybe it could be worded better but its still verbose - besides, you can quickly find the same information just by looking at the source code.

When you think about it the message is valid (even if it doesn't tell the whole story) - It is *possible* to cast from `Bar` to `Foo`, but in this particular case the CLR was unable to perform this cast.

Comment: It's easy to spot an error in the code that I provided, it's not so easy when the method is longer or contains implicitly typed variables (which I wouldn't use in this case, but some people do). In this particular case the information about `obj` being of type `Bar` is redundant while the information about the way it's referenced is crucial. That's the way I see it

Answer (score 0):

It's in your code:

```
public static explicit operator Foo(Bar bar) {
```

It might work it it becomes:

```
public static implicit operator Foo(Bar bar) {
```

Or, you can write:

```
Foo foo = (Foo)(Bar)bar;
```